# Dense sets on the metric space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let  $
{(}{X}{,}\mathit{\rho}{)}
$
be metric space

1)Show that the complementary of no where dense set is every where dense.
is the converse is right ? Give an example.

2)on the same metric space .Show that the closure of no where dense set is no where dense too .

Comment: I think both problems are best solved (weirdly enough) by studying open sets. For instance, for problem 1), look at the _definition_ of nowhere dense. What does that say about any given open set and the complement of the nowhere dense set?

Comment: What *Is* your definition of nowhere dense. In my definition, 2. is trivial